# Getting facebook likes on facebook to translate to on page likes

Tags: php, facebook

If I share a link from my website directly on my websites facebook page and it's liked there, it translates to likes on the actual website page (the like counter increases). I've figured out how to automatically post through php to my websites facebook page but the likes on facebook don't translate to likes on the actual page that's shared. Is there a way to make this happen?

meta tags all appear to be correct, still don't have the likes translating

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Open Graph documentation, it sounds like when people are sharing your link it is sharing the root of the site rather then the actual link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

You will need to define url of the link on each page so that Facebook knows where to redirect to and treat it separate from your page likes.

Comment: It's not people sharing the link though. I'm intending to run a cron job but for now im just doing tests.  I'm using $facebook->api('/PAGEID/feed', 'post', argArray) to post to the page wall. The link parameter in the argArray is the full link of the page Im trying to share. It's pulling all the right info in the facebook wall post but the likes on facebook aren't translating to likes on the page that's linked to

Comment: It's the same thing, the link is being share (by your cron job or by a person) where does the link take you if you click it? your root or your actual link?

Comment: The link is the full link of the article im sharing

Comment: We were previously using NetworkedBlogs to do this for us but switched it to our own stuff to accomplish this synched liking

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the open graph meta tags will help solve your issue, it treats each article as a separate page.

Comment: I was missing the og:url meta tag. I fixed this but the likes from facebook still don't seem to propagate to the actual article

Comment: Facebook most likely needs to scrape your page, or you can force it using their linter tool, http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: So I've done that and fixed another meta tag I was missing. It's still not translating the likes from facebook to likes on the actual page. The linter tool shows the likes from the article page itself on the bottom section. But the likes on the actual facebook page aren't shown.

Comment: Let me clarify: 1) you want the likes of an article to show up on the article page? 2) the likes for your article are not not contributing to your root page likes?

Comment: I want the likes on articles shared on our company's facebook page to translate to likes on the articles page that is being shared. So when a user on facebook likes one of our shared articles, the like counter on that articles page (on our site) is updated

Comment: what is the code that is being use on your site to display the facebook likes?

Comment: <fb:like href="<? echo urlencode("PAGEURL"); ?>"  send="true" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="50" action="like" font="arial" colorscheme="light" />
</fb:like>

Comment: on the article display page take out the href. are you displaying the like buttons outside of the actual article page? if so you need to make sure that the href is pointing to the right page otherwise you will have the same issue. I'm hoping that PAGEURL is the actual link to the article. it also looks like you have the special quotes and not actual double quotes

Comment: pageurl is just a placeholder, the actual code has the legit link. ill take out the href on the like button and see if that helps. The quotes are all just standard quotes.

Comment: i removed the href and it doesnt seem to have had any effect towards solving the issue

Comment: this is the article i performed the latest test on without the href : http://www.trendhunter.com/trends/dorothy1

Comment: this is the facebook page i auto shared it to: http://www.facebook.com/trendhunter

Comment: I believe that trendhunter has an app id for their page you will need to use in order to get the same number of likes from their facebook page, I'm guess it is 474656278724 but I'm not sure. right now what page id are you using (as in whose page is it)?

Comment: There's an Appid for the trendhunter app which im using to post to the wall. There's also an id for the actual trendhunter page. Which are you referring to and how should it be used to sync the likes?

Comment: there is a different meta tag for app id I would try using that or use the facebook page id in place of the app id currently

Comment: it actually said the app_id was invalid in lint if i tried using the page_id

Comment: I received this comment from the facebook forum :I'm sure someone will be along shortly to confirm but I think the difference you're seeing is because a share is not the same as a feed post. A share is sharing a link whereas the feed post is creating a post in FB. So with the first one, the likes are attributed directly to the link and with the second, the likes are attributed to the FB post.